# Delete only the particular Div Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="@("Bottomgrid)" class="dgd2"></div>
```

```js
var element = document.getElementById("#Bottomgrid");
element.empty();

$('.dgd2').empty()
```

Instead of deleting only Bottom grid its also removing other Div present in the  screen.

Comment: show other div html ,,, does they have same id or class?

Comment: I think you mean `document.getElementById("#Bottomgrid").remove()`

Comment: what id do you give the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div id="item1">Hey</div>
</div>
```

you can simply just use this pure JavaScript code to remove the "item1" element:

```
var element = document.getElementById("item1");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) will remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

While jQuery [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) will remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Considering if you have your HTML as below :

```
<div id="Bottomgrid" class="dgd2"></div>
```

and you want to remove div with `id="Bottomgrid"`
Then your javascript code will be :

```
$("#Bottomgrid").remove();

//This is not required as far as I see
//$('.dgd2').empty()
```

Answer (score 0):

.empty() doesn't remove element it only removes elements children. use `$('#Bottomgrid').remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript :

```
document.getElementById("Bottomgrid").remove();
```

Jquery:

```
$( "#Bottomgrid" ).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give the div name properly like Below how I am writing the Id. also you need to check properly which div you are going to delete. Because if a nested div present in your page and you are going to delete the div which is having all the child div inside that , then all respective div going to be deleted .

### Html

```
                  <div id="bottomgridDiv" class="dgd2">
                        <div id="parentDiv" class="dgd2">
                            <div id="childDiv" class="dgd2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

### Javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById("#bottomgridDiv");

  In JQuery:-
$("#bottomgridDiv").remove();
```

So now if you wants to delete the bottomgridDiv then what ever the div present inside this is going to delete.